# Python elif statements are changing type from float to list

Tags: python, if-statement

First time posting so apologizes if formatting is incorrect. My program has 2 lists for now. I I will be adding 4 more after solving this initial issue. One for and item the user selects, and a second  with prices for the each item. I have written a code for user selection which runs.

My issue comes with the code for the program associating the item selected with the price list. My first if statement registers item_price as a float, which I gives me what I need. Item_price in the following elif statements are being seen as a list. How can I change them to a float so that the price prints instead of the list?

```
food=["burger", "pizza", "hotdogs", "tacos"]
food_price=[8.99, 22.50, 3.50, 6.00]

def get_menu_item(item,item_list,):

    phrase = "Would you like" + item + "? [y/n] "

    response = input(phrase)

    if response == "y":
        print("Here are your menu options:", item_list)

        idx = input("please enter the item you would like from our menu[1,2,3,4]: ")

        idx = int(idx) -1

        return item_list[idx]
        

#if user selects [n]
    else:
        return (None)


#item price function

def get_item_price(item_price,item,item_list):

    if item == item_list[0]:
        item_price = item_price[0]
        
    elif item == item_list[1]:
        item_price == item_price[1]
        
    elif item == item_list[2]:
        item_price == item_price[2]
        
    elif item == item_list[3]:
        item_price == item_price[3]

    return item_price

entree_choice = get_menu_item(" dinner",food)

print('You have selected: ' + entree_choice + ".")

entree_price = get_item_price(food_price,entree_choice,food)

print(entree_price)
```

Comment: `item_price == item_price[1]` is a typo. You should use assignment (`=`) instead of comparison (`==`)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I answered this for myself shortly after. I was using == instead of = for all of my elif statements. I feel dumb but writing this out helped me solve it.

Answer (score 0):

You could simplify things further by using a dictionary to store your data :

```
food_price = {"burger":8.99, "pizza":22.50, "hotdogs":3.50, "tacos":6.00}

def get_menu_item(item,item_list,):
    phrase = "Would you like" + item + "? [y/n] "
    response = input(phrase)
    if response == "y":
        print("Here are your menu options:", item_list)
        idx = input("please enter the item you would like from our menu[1,2,3,4]: ")
        idx = int(idx) -1
        return item_list[idx]
        
    else:
        return (None)

entree_choice = get_menu_item(" dinner",food)
print('You have selected: ' + entree_choice + ".")
# if entree_choice is not found in the food_price dictionary, the output becomes the string "Entree choice not available."
entree_price = food_price.get(entree_choice, "Entree choice not available.") 
print(entree_price)
```